# How to resize div when dragging top left?

Tags: html, css, resize, draggable

In CSS3 [resize](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp), the icon to resize is positioned in the bottom right. How do I make it appear in the top left and make the user able to resize accordingly?

I've found [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#resize):

> The precise direction of resizing (i.e. altering the top left of the element or altering the bottom right) may depend on a number of factors including whether the element is absolutely positioned, whether it is positioned using the ‘right’ and ‘bottom’ properties, whether the language of the element is right-to-left etc. The precise direction of resizing is left to the UA to properly determine for the platform.

So far, managed to place the icon in the bottom left using:

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    resize: both;
    overflow: auto;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: Any code or demo available?

Comment: I doubt you can as this is handled by the browser. Also, `direction: rtl` has other implications that I suspect you don't want.

Comment: rtl complications don't bother me since I have another div which sets directions: initial; Works as expected :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, it is handled by the User Agent (but you can [try rotating it](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-resize/) :)

Honestly, I agree with [the one commenting](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-resize/#comment-8310) that the whole resize property thing should have been left out of the standards:

> This shouldn’t be in the standard. Resizable textboxes are a user
> agent feature to help mitigate poor design, and giving developers the
> option to it is madness. If I as a user want to resize a textbox to
> help me enter text, then that should be up to me. The developer has no
> idea about the screen resolution, DPI, and physical dimensions of my
> device, or any special accessibility overrides or user stylesheets I
> have applied, and therefore no way to say I don’t need to resize
> something.

Amen :/

Comment: I can see your point and it makes sense indeed. Until someone like me comes along who doesn't want to implement codes of Javascript to manipulate the DOM and is happy with a simple solution.

Comment: Without messing with javascript, the *only* solution is: let to the browser (and every browser will put it in bottom right corner of the element). It's not a big deal, but you have no choice. It is a "you can't" answer, but still it is the right answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the last line from what you quoted:

> The precise direction of resizing is left to the UA to properly determine for the platform.

That means the default behavior is browser specific and you can't hack it.

Your only other option is to do the resizing with **JavaScript**.

A quick Google search led me to this: http://rightjs.org/ui/resizable/demo

Though I am sure you could do this without the JavaScript Library overhead.